# Invalid Hook: Can't pass setState function through Context Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm new to React and I'm trying to create a user state global context using a context provider so that on submission of the login form, the username and role are updated in the global context with the response of a successful request.

The code for my app is as follows:

```
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

//PAGES AND COMPONENTS
import Registration from './components/registration/Registration';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import Login from './components/login/Login';

//GLOBAL CONTEXTS
import {AuthProvider} from './context/AuthContext'


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>  
          <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}></Route>
              <Route path='/Register' element={<Registration/>}></Route>
              <Route path='/Login' element={<Login/>}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code for my Provider (AuthContext.js) is the following:

```
const AuthContext= React.createContext();
const AuthUpdateContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth(){
    return useContext (AuthContext);
}

export function useAuthUpdate(){
    return useContext(AuthUpdateContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({children}){
    const [authState,setAuthState]=useState({
                                                id:0,
                                                username:"",
                                                role:"user"
                                            });

   
    

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authState}>
            <AuthUpdateContext.Provider value={setAuthState}>
                {children}
            </AuthUpdateContext.Provider>    
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

And the code that's throwing the Invalid Hook error is the following:

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Formik, Form, Field,ErrorMessage} from 'formik'
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import './Login.css';
import {useAuth,useAuthUpdate} from '../../context/AuthContext'


function Login() {
  const navigate=useNavigate();
  const [invalidCredentials,setInvalidCredentials]=useState("");
  const setAuthState=useAuthUpdate;
  const useAuthState=useAuth();

  
  const onSubmit=(data)=>{
      axios
            .post('http://localhost:3001/User/Login',data)
            .catch((error)=>{
              setInvalidCredentials("Invalid Credentials. Please try again.")
            })
            .then((response)=>{
              localStorage.setItem("token",response.data.token);
              setAuthState((prev)=>({
                ...prev,
                id:response.data.id,
                username:response.data.username,
                role:response.data.role
              }))
              

            })
            .then(()=>{
              console.log(useAuthState);
              navigate('/');
            })
  }

  const validationSchema=Yup.object().shape({
    usernameOrEmail:Yup
                .string()
                .required('Field must not be blank.'),
    password:Yup.string()
                .required('Field must not be blank.'),
});

  const initialValues ={
    usernameOrEmail:"",
    password:"",
        };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
      </div>

      <div className='row'>
        <h2>Log-in Here:</h2>
      </div>

      <Formik onSubmit={onSubmit} validationSchema={validationSchema} initialValues={initialValues}>
        <Form>
          <div className='row'>
            <label>Username/Email</label>
            <Field name='usernameOrEmail'></Field>
            <ErrorMessage name="usernameOrEmail">
                                    {msg=><div className="errorMsg">{msg}</div>}
            </ErrorMessage>
          </div>
          <div className='row'>
            <label>Password</label>
            <Field  name='password'
                    type='password'/>
            <ErrorMessage name="password">
                                    {msg=><div className="errorMsg">{msg}</div>}
            </ErrorMessage>
          </div>
          
          <div id="register-btn"className="row">
                    <button className="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" >Login</button>
          </div>

          <div className='row'>
            <span className='errorMsg'>{invalidCredentials}</span>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

What I find weird is that both `useAuthState` and `setAuthState` are React Hooks, and I've positioned them in the same way, but when I console.log `useAuthState`, it logs it as :
{id:0, username:"", role:"user"}, whereas when I call `setAuthState`, it throws me the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
>    at `Object.throwInvalidHookError` (react-dom.development.js:16227:1)
>    at `useContext` (react.development.js:1618:1)
>    at `useAuthUpdate`(AuthContext.js:12:1)
>    at Login.js:25:1

Comment: I think you meant to use `const setAuthState = useAuthUpdate()` (you are missing the `()`). FYI, you don't need to use two contexts; it's reasonably common to put both state and setter in the same context

Comment: When I do that, I don't get the error, but the console.log(useAuthState) returns to me an unchanged object. That is: "{id: 0, username: '', role: 'user'}".
The reasoning behind not putting parentheses is that I want to import the function setAuthState, not the result of it. Am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: [State updates are asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/283366). Stop using `console.log()` to verify state and start using your actual application

Comment: You were absolutely right on both counts!
I used react dev tools and they showed that the component WAS updating.
I'm still left wondering why I needed to add the parentheses after useAuthUpdate.
Shouldn't useAuthUpdate==setAuthState since useContext returns the value of the context?

Comment: Because `useAuthUpdate` is a function that returns the context value which is itself, a function